# python non blocking recv with pipe between processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, inter-process-communicat

Seen this line of code but could not find documentation

```
self.conn.setblocking(0)
```

The question is, how do you poll a pool of pipes without blocking?
Got a parent process that needs to communicate with some unstable child processes and wish to poll and check periodically if they've something to say. Do not wish to block if they decide they need more time before they have something new to say. Will this magically do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely what you were looking at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking

You don't give much detail so I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but usually when you have a number of sockets that you want to poll, you will use [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) (see these [examples](http://pymotw.com/2/select/) from PyMOTW).

Comment: Is a pipe between processes a socket as well?

Comment: Not sure which pipes you are talking about, but that is a socket function so self.conn is almost certainly a socket.  Most "pipes" will be implemented underneath by some sort of socket too.

Comment: Ended up using select and it works perfectly with pipes for our needs

Comment: I would upvote this if someone could provide some minimum example code. Getting an error on windows and the documentation is conflicted (some places says select works on win but poll doesn't, some places says unix only for all). If we had some known working code I could check to see if it's a platform issue or what I'm missing :)

Answer (score 3):

Creating a pipe will return two connection objects. A connection object offers the polling functionality, where you can check if there is anything to read. Polling functionality allows you to specify a timeout to wait for.

If you have a group of connection objects that you are waiting on, then you can use multiprocessing.connection.wait(), or the non-multiprocessing version of it.

For details , see 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection
which will show you the connection object details. Look at the poll function

Answer (score 0):

you can check p.poll(0) then if the result was True then the pipe is not empty and you can receive the data without blocking .